# Cycles alpha background, noise on edges

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, shadows, noise-reduction

I am new to blender and i want to render some images with transparent background.
This image is rendered with cycles and the shadows are generated on a plane with Shadow catcher.

The problem is that the edges of the objects come out with noise. I tried different lighting methods, higher number of samples but nothing helped.
If i render with background then it looks fine, there is no noise.

I want to keep using Cycled to have it looking as realistic as possible.

In the belwo image the white background is added in Gimp.

[image: the white background is added in Gimp]

Comment: I guess you compose some passes or view layers. Could you show screenshots of that?

Comment: I did noting in the composer. In the meantime i figured out what to do, i increased the number of samples up to 100 and not it looks good. I will delete this post.